# Using awk to get nameserver info from nslookup

Tags: awk, sed, while-loop, nslookup

Hello I am trying to pull the ns records for a few domains we own. I want to script it so the data is formatted in
domain name, ns record, ns record, ns record
domain name, ns record, ns record, ns record
domain name, ns record, ns record, ns record

What I am getting is

domain name, ns record, ns record, ns record
ns record, domain name, ns record, ns record
ns record, ns record, domain name, ns record

here is the command I have got so far but it organises in alphabetic order.

Input

```
cat dom.txt
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
```

```
awk '{print}' < dom.txt | while read domain; do nslookup -type=ns $domain | grep nameserver | sed -e 's/nameserver =//g' -e 's/.$//' | awk '{print $1 "\n" $2}' | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//' | awk '{print}'; done
```

Comment: Please show use sample input & **expected output**

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way, using `dig` and shell: tested mostly `bourne`* `bash`, `dash`, `ash`, `yash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `sh` (but not `csh` & `fish` compliant):

```
$ cat dom.txt 
example.org
w3c.org
gnu.org
```

```
$ while read domain; do
      echo "$domain,$(dig +short NS "$domain" | paste -sd ',')"
  done < dom.txt
```

##### Output

```
example.org,a.iana-servers.net.,b.iana-servers.net.
w3c.org,ns-139-c.gandi.net.,ns-225-a.gandi.net.,ns-206-b.gandi.net.
gnu.org,ns3.gnu.org.,ns2.gnu.org.,ns1.gnu.org.
```